# Javascript equivalent for Inverse normal function ? eg Excel's NORMSINV() or NORMINV()?

Tags: javascript, math, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm trying to convert something from my excel spreadsheets into Javascript and came along the NORMSINV() macro in my spreadsheets.

The NormSInv() is nicely documented at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/normsinv-HP005209195.aspx. Basically it's of the form
Z = NormSInv(probability) where if you give it the probability (say 0.90), it gives you the Z value for a standard normal distribution (Z= 1.33).

I could encode the entire transformation table as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table but want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

So, is there such a function in Javascript? eg. in Javascript's math libraries (if there is such a thing!).

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up implementing the NormSInv() in javascript myself. No point in including an entire stats library when I need just one function

```
function NormSInv(p) {
    var a1 = -39.6968302866538, a2 = 220.946098424521, a3 = -275.928510446969;
    var a4 = 138.357751867269, a5 = -30.6647980661472, a6 = 2.50662827745924;
    var b1 = -54.4760987982241, b2 = 161.585836858041, b3 = -155.698979859887;
    var b4 = 66.8013118877197, b5 = -13.2806815528857, c1 = -7.78489400243029E-03;
    var c2 = -0.322396458041136, c3 = -2.40075827716184, c4 = -2.54973253934373;
    var c5 = 4.37466414146497, c6 = 2.93816398269878, d1 = 7.78469570904146E-03;
    var d2 = 0.32246712907004, d3 = 2.445134137143, d4 = 3.75440866190742;
    var p_low = 0.02425, p_high = 1 - p_low;
    var q, r;
    var retVal;

    if ((p < 0) || (p > 1))
    {
        alert("NormSInv: Argument out of range.");
        retVal = 0;
    }
    else if (p < p_low)
    {
        q = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(p));
        retVal = (((((c1 * q + c2) * q + c3) * q + c4) * q + c5) * q + c6) / ((((d1 * q + d2) * q + d3) * q + d4) * q + 1);
    }
    else if (p <= p_high)
    {
        q = p - 0.5;
        r = q * q;
        retVal = (((((a1 * r + a2) * r + a3) * r + a4) * r + a5) * r + a6) * q / (((((b1 * r + b2) * r + b3) * r + b4) * r + b5) * r + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        q = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(1 - p));
        retVal = -(((((c1 * q + c2) * q + c3) * q + c4) * q + c5) * q + c6) / ((((d1 * q + d2) * q + d3) * q + d4) * q + 1);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing that I know of embedded into JavaScript's core.

You might like to take a look at the [JStat JavaScript library](https://github.com/jstat/jstat). This seems to offer a range of functions for statistical calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although it's a valid response, I ended up implementing the NormSInv() in javascript myself. No point in including an entire stats library when I need just one function...

Comment: Assuming you don't make any mistakes :)

Comment: The JStat project now resides at https://github.com/jstat/jstat

Answer (score 3):

i extracted the `jStat.distribution.normal.inv` into a standalone function you can use with webpack as a closure (or just by itself).

`import normalinv from 'jsfile'`
`let yourMath = normalinv()`

or

`var yourMath = normalinv();`
`yourMath(p, m, d)`

```
export default function normalinv() {
  function erfcinv(p) {
    var j = 0;
    var x, err, t, pp;
    if (p >= 2)
      return -100;
    if (p <= 0)
      return 100;
    pp = (p < 1) ? p : 2 - p;
    t = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(pp / 2));
    x = -0.70711 * ((2.30753 + t * 0.27061) /
      (1 + t * (0.99229 + t * 0.04481)) - t);
    for (; j < 2; j++) {
      err = erfc(x) - pp;
      x += err / (1.12837916709551257 * Math.exp(-x * x) - x * err);
    }
    return (p < 1) ? x : -x;
  }

  function erfc(x) {
    return 1 - erf(x);
  }

  function erf(x) {
    var cof = [-1.3026537197817094, 6.4196979235649026e-1, 1.9476473204185836e-2,
      -9.561514786808631e-3, -9.46595344482036e-4, 3.66839497852761e-4,
      4.2523324806907e-5, -2.0278578112534e-5, -1.624290004647e-6,
      1.303655835580e-6, 1.5626441722e-8, -8.5238095915e-8,
      6.529054439e-9, 5.059343495e-9, -9.91364156e-10,
      -2.27365122e-10, 9.6467911e-11, 2.394038e-12,
      -6.886027e-12, 8.94487e-13, 3.13092e-13,
      -1.12708e-13, 3.81e-16, 7.106e-15,
      -1.523e-15, -9.4e-17, 1.21e-16,
      -2.8e-17
    ];
    var j = cof.length - 1;
    var isneg = false;
    var d = 0;
    var dd = 0;
    var t, ty, tmp, res;

    if (x < 0) {
      x = -x;
      isneg = true;
    }

    t = 2 / (2 + x);
    ty = 4 * t - 2;

    for (; j > 0; j--) {
      tmp = d;
      d = ty * d - dd + cof[j];
      dd = tmp;
    }

    res = t * Math.exp(-x * x + 0.5 * (cof[0] + ty * d) - dd);
    return isneg ? res - 1 : 1 - res;
  }

  return function inv(p, mean, std) {
    return -1.41421356237309505 * std * erfcinv(2 * p) + mean;
  }
}
```