# JavaScript appending SVG animations. How to start them up?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I expanded my learning code from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33709741/5487882), to learn how to append SVG animations using JavaScript. I tried this way:

(I didn't include the definition of the function `NormSInv()` to save space. If needed it is the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843728/5487882)).

```
      function randomPath(){
      var x = 500;
      var y = 400;
      var xstep = 0;
      var ystep = 0;
      var path = '500,400';
      for (var k = 0; k < 3 ; k++) {
          path += ' ';
          path += (x).toString();
          path += ',';
          path += (y).toString();
          xstep = NormSInv(Math.random());
          ystep = NormSInv(Math.random());
          xstep *= 10;
          ystep *= 10;
          x += Math.trunc(xstep);
          y += Math.trunc(ystep);
        };
        return path;
      };

      window.onload = function() {

    var figure = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
    figure.id = 'brownian-figure';
    figure.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    figure.setAttribute('width', '100%');

    var pathArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    pathArray[i] = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','polyline');
    pathArray[i].id = "hair" + (i).toString();
    var path = randomPath();
    pathArray[i].setAttribute('points', path);
    pathArray[i].setAttribute('style', 'fill:none;stroke:rgba(0,0,20,1);stroke-width:1');
    figure.appendChild(pathArray[i]);
    };

    var divfigure = document.createElement('div');
    divfigure.id = 'divfigure';
    divfigure.onclick = moveHair;
    divfigure.style = 'margin:0pt;padding:0pt;border:0pt none;background-color:rgba(240,240,240,0.66);position:absolute;top:0vh;left:0vw;width:50vw;height:99vh;';
    divfigure.appendChild(figure);


    var content = document.getElementById('content-container');
    document.body.insertBefore(divfigure, content);
  };

  function moveHair(){
    var a_hair_number = Math.trunc(10 * Math.random());
    var paths = document.getElementById('brownian-figure').childNodes;
    var hair = paths[a_hair_number];
    var animation = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');
    animation.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#hair' + a_hair_number.toString());
    animation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'points');
    animation.setAttribute('dur', '2s');
    animation.setAttribute('repeatCount', 'indefinite');
    animation.setAttribute('from', hair.getAttribute('points'));
    animation.setAttribute('values', hair.getAttribute('points') + '; ' + randomPath() + '; ' + hair.getAttribute('points'));
    animation.setAttribute('to', hair.getAttribute('points'));
    var divfigure = document.getElementById('brownian-figure');
    divfigure.appendChild(animation);
  };
```

The problematic part is the function `moveHair()`, at the end. The code runs, and does insert the animations with the attributes as they are expected to be. I can see it happening by inspecting the page with FireBug. **But nothing moves.**

An example (part of it to make it shorter) of the SVG I see in FireBug is

```
<svg id="brownian-figure" height="100%" width="100%">
  <polyline id="hair3" points="500,400 500,400 521,390 510,374" style="fill:none;stroke:rgba(0,0,20,1);stroke-width:1">
  <animate xlink:href="#hair3" attributeName="points" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="500,400 500,400 521,390 510,374" values="500,400 500,400 521,390 510,374; 500,400 500,400 508,419 515,440; 500,400 500,400 521,390 510,374" to="500,400 500,400 521,390 510,374">
</svg>
```

If I use this SVG code directly, it does work and things move.

Is it a problem with the namespaces? At first I was creating the `animate` with `createElement` and they were showing gray in the FireBug inspector. Then I wen to create them using `createElementNS` and using the same namespace as the SVG and its children nodes. Doing this makes the `animate`s appear properly in the FireBug inspector. But they are still not making anything move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("elem")
var anim = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate")
anim.setAttribute("begin", "indefinite")
anim.setAttribute("from", 10)
anim.setAttribute("to", 50)
anim.setAttribute("fill", "freeze")
anim.setAttribute("dur", "1s")
anim.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite")
anim.setAttribute("attributeName", "r")

elem.appendChild(anim)


function startAnim() {
  anim.beginElement()
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <circle id="elem" cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="orange" />
</svg>

<button type="button" onclick="startAnim()">start animation</button>
```

You don't set the begin Attribute which defaults to 0s (document time)... In short, you habe to set begin to "indefinite" and call animation.beginElement() after appending the animation.

Comment: Just gave it a try. I added `animation.setAttribute('begin', 'indefinite');` before the `appendChild` line and `animation.beginElement();` after the `appendChild` line. It didn't work, although it sounds reasonable what you are saying.

Comment: Does the variable `animation` keep pointing to the `animate` object after appending it to the `svg`? I am asking to make sure that the line `animation.beginElement()` is in fact asking that particular animation to begin.

Comment: I tried now to put `begin=accessKey(s)` such that I can try to trigger the start manually by pressing 's'. It didn't work either.

Comment: oh... and when i change your`moveHair()` signature to `moveHair(evt)`
and then do evt.target.appendChild(animation) so using nested animation instead of targeting your Elements with xlink:href it does work as well

Comment: I got it to work now. Thank you very much. The `xlink:href` wasn't working for me either. I still need to understand why. I made it work by doing what you said, on nesting the animate inside the polylines.